# Jquery doesn't bind to new appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, element, bind

I find out that by default JQuery doens't bind the new inserted elements.
Here is a snippet which shows what I'm trying to explain.

http://jsfiddle.net/8hf5r/2/

```
$('#chg-em').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.local').empty().append('<p id="orange-juice">orange juice<p>');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#orange-juice").on('click', function() {
    alert('ola');
});
```

Which might be the solution? :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegated events :

```
$(".local").on('click', '#orange-juice', function() {
    alert('ola');
});
```

Learn about delegated event here : http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events